# What is the difference between O(n) and o(n)?

Tags: algorithms

I was studying Big-Oh notation, and there is apparently a difference between $O(n)$ and $o(n)$. What is it?

I think $f(n)$ is $o(n)$ means that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$$ but what does this mean?

Comment: This question has been [answered on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/can-someone-please-explain-the-difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation).

Comment: This question is one of those "kind of fits here because there's no really good place to put it" sort of questions. Stack Overflow is more applied, but they'd take it because performance matters sometimes. We'd take it for similar reasons. It's conceptually important for programming, so Programmers might take it. The CS proposal in Area 51 would take it. Topicality isn't an issue here. Since it duplicates a question on another site in the network, it's not quite a duplicate, but I feel like the best course of action is to close and leave this question up as a signpost, along with James' link.

Comment: By the way, the "too localized" bit is a canard. I can't close it because it's a duplicate because there's no duplicate on scicomp, and like I said, topicality isn't an issue. It's just...not worth leaving open in its current form, even though it's a good question for a computational scientist to understand.

Comment: It really seems like it should be part of a wiki description of asymptotic notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it like the difference between <= versus <.  If we say that a <= b, it is possible that a can equal b.  If a < b, then a & b can never be equal in magnitude, and a is always strictly smaller than b.

With Big Oh notation, if we say $f(n) = O(g(n))$, then the function g(n) forms an asymptotic bound for f(n), but f(n) can come within a constant factor of g(n) in the limit (we sometimes call this an asymptotically tight bound).  But if $f(n) = o(g(n))$, then g(n) always grows faster than f(n) in the limit.  Thus, f(n) can't come within a constant factor away from g(n).  In little oh notation, g(n) is MUCH LARGER (than a constant factor) away from f(n) in the limit.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that makes sense. So 5logn is o(n^2), but O(logn). That makes sense!

Comment: This answer is almost right, $f(n)$ can be larger than $g(n)$ in the $O(n)$ case, imagine $O(1)$, $f$ could be very large with a corresponding large $k$.  The description for $o(g(n))$ is spot on.

Comment: @AronAhmadia: You're right... I didn't even think about that possibility.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article on Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), particularly the section on Bachmann-Landau Notation, is a well-written description of the different notations used in algorithmic complexity analysis.